# Causing balls to collide in a simple ball bounce program

Tags: java, animation

I have a simple ball bounce program in which the balls bounce of the sides of my frame fine. I tried to add a way for the balls to bounce off each other by checking if two balls were touching by creating a rectangle around each ball and checking if any other ball intersects that rectangle, and if they do switch their velocities. It works fine when I add the code that has ** around it and there is only one ball but as soon as I add more than one they start moving together until they get stuck out of the frame. I have no idea what is wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BallBounceFrame
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new BallBounceFrame();
}

JFrame frame;
JPanel controlPanel;
JButton stop, start;
JSpinner ballNum;
Timer t;
BallCanvas c;
static int WIDTH = 500;
static int HEIGHT = 500;

public BallBounceFrame()
{   
    frame = new JFrame("Bouncing Balls");
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    c = new BallCanvas(0, 20);
    frame.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    addPanels();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    t = new Timer(10, new animator());
    t.start();
}

public void addPanels()
{
    controlPanel = new JPanel();
        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new buttonControlListener());
        controlPanel.add(start);

        stop = new JButton("Stop");
        stop.addActionListener(new buttonControlListener());
        controlPanel.add(stop);

        ballNum = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 1000, 1));
        ballNum.addChangeListener(new spinnerControlListener());
        controlPanel.add(ballNum);

    frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

class BallCanvas extends JPanel
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();

    public BallCanvas(int ballNum, int ballSize)
    {
        setBalls(ballNum, ballSize);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        for(Ball b : balls)
        {
            b.move(this.getSize());
            g2.fill(b);
        }
    }

    public void animate()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                frame.repaint();
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public void setBalls(int ballNum, int ballSize)
    {
        balls.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < ballNum; i++)
        {
            balls.add(new Ball(ballSize, balls));
        }
    }
}

class Ball extends Ellipse2D.Float
{
    private int xVel, yVel;
    private int size;
    private ArrayList<Ball> balls;

    public Ball(int size, ArrayList<Ball> balls)
    {
        super((int) (Math.random() * (BallBounceFrame.WIDTH /(1.1)) + 1), (int) (Math.random() * (BallBounceFrame.WIDTH /(1.3)) + 7), size, size);
        this.size = size;
        this.xVel = (int) (Math.random() * 7 + 2);
        this.yVel = (int) (Math.random() * 7 + 2);
        this.balls = balls;
    }

    public void move(Dimension panelSize)
    {
        **Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Float(super.x, super.y, size, size);
        for(Ball b : balls)
        {
            if(b != this && b.intersects(r));
            {
                int tempx = xVel;
                int tempy = yVel;
                xVel = b.xVel;
                yVel = b.yVel;
                b.xVel = tempx;
                b.yVel = tempy;
                break;
            }
        }**

        if(super.x < 0 || super.x > panelSize.getWidth() - size) xVel *= -1;
        if(super.y < 5 || super.y > panelSize.getHeight() - size) yVel *= -1;
        super.x += xVel;
        super.y += yVel;
    }
}
class animator implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

class buttonControlListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == stop) t.stop();

        if(e.getSource() == start) t.start();
    }
}

class spinnerControlListener implements ChangeListener
{
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == ballNum)
        {
            int balls = (int) ballNum.getValue();
            c.setBalls(balls, 20);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code has a single `ArrayList<Ball>` inside `BallCanvas` - the 'master' list - and then each `Ball` has its own `ArrayList<Ball>` representing the list of balls the were created up until that time. `Ball` then only uses its own `ArrayList<Ball>` inside the `move()` method.

May I suggest that you only have one, master `ArrayList<Ball>` inside `BallCanvas`? Instead of passing it in to the `Ball` constructor, pass it in to the `move()` call.